# Acces on-premise AD users via Azure product to move them to Azure AD B2C

Tags: active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We need to move users from an on-premise Active Directory on Windows Server (not Azure Active Directory) to Azure AD B2C. But, we're having difficulty in trying to figure out how to read the user data from the AD using Azure products.

We're thinking about using one of the following Azure products to read from on-premise AD, but it's surprisingly difficult to find if this is possible or not, much less how to do it:

- Azure Data Factory
- Azure Logic App
- Microsoft Power Platform [Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/data-platform-intro) (formerly Common Data Service)
- Power BI [Data Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-introduction-self-service)
- Note: We can't use Azure AD Connect to migrate the users because that tool isn't designed to work with B2C. Reference Microsoft's [Azure AD B2C: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-i-use-azure-ad-connect-to-migrate-consumer-identities-that-are-stored-on-my-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure-ad-b2c).

The Microsoft article [Migrate users to Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration) says that a script needs to be written that uses the Microsoft Graph API to create user accounts in Azure AD B2C. But the article doesn't give advice on how to access the source data, which in our case is AD.

Comment: You can use PowerShell cmdlet [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) to get the AD users and then import them into Azure B2C via calling Microsoft Graph [Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is there anything unclear?

Comment: Thank you, Allen. Your suggestion seems to be the way to go. We didn't find an easier way than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-box Azure product/solution that connects to on-prem AD. Maybe there is a way which requires you create custom connector and custom API for querying AD users. See [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b4d01d5b-99e5-4a78-9009-0dc94c00048c/logic-app-connector-for-ldap?forum=azurelogicapps).

The quickest way is using PowerShell cmdlet [Get-ADUser](http://Get-ADUser) to export the AD users and then import them into Azure B2C via Microsoft Graph [Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).